# Play module - Play application different in entity database

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to know, is play module can have entity from database? or entity must be placed in PLay application? I am using hibernate, and play framework version 1.2.5. And how about hibernate.cfg.xml file, and HibernateUtil.java file are they must be placed in play application too? thank you, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

in youre version of play there is an plugin hibernate,

in version 2 only persistent.xml have to be put in the play application, so i think you have to read documentation of your version of play :

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/configuration